# Is there a more transparent way to access the root of a Node.js application besides process.cwd()?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

Is there a more transparent way to access the root of a Node.js application besides process.cwd()? - I am aware this is pretty transparent but I am just curious for those who may pick up the application later on and don't know what cwd() might infer.

To clarify - if my applicaiton lives in /var/www/node-app, I want to access that path from /var/www/node-app/any/nested/path.

Answer (score 0):

Root if a Node.js application is `__dirname`, not `process.cwd()`

ps: wait... technically there is no such thing as a root of the application. So you should clarify what do you mean by that.

Comment: __dirname returns the current directory of the script in which __dirname is called from.  so if i have app/views/script.js and print __dirname - I will be returned /../../app/views

Comment: Yes. And process.cwd can be changed by process.chdir().

Comment: ... so if you need process current directory, just use process.cwd()... this what it is for :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an app called node-app in the path var/www/node-app with an entry point as index.js. Then define the following in index.js

```
  exports.path = __dirname;
```

Now assuming the other app is in var/www/some-other-deeper-path/new-app, and we require to know the path at which node-app is, we have to require node-app in new-app using

```
  var node-app = require('node-app');
  console.log(node-app.path); // this will log var/www/node-app
```

Comment: How about `app.set('root', __dirname)` in the index.js?  Then just calling `app.set('root')` anywhere in the applicaiton?